# How can I join one-to-two linked tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (let's call them Event and Person) in MySQL that are directly linked (Person has a column "event_id" that corresponds to "id" in Event). I wanted to create a view of all the Events, that would also have the name and address of the linked Person. My assumption was that there was never more than one Person to an Event, and thus I created this query:

```
CREATE VIEW EventWithPerson AS
  (SELECT
    Event.id,
    Event.last_updated,
    Event.description,
    Person.name AS person_name,
    Person.address AS person_address
  FROM Event
    LEFT JOIN Person
      ON Event.id = Person.event_id);
```

However, I have since discovered that there are a handful of Events that have *two* corresponding Persons (but never more than 2). Whereas my old view had the columns "person_name, person_address", the view I want to create would have "person1_name, person1_address, person2_name, person2_address". The original query I wrote just keeps one of the Persons and drops the other. How could I modify it to keep both Persons? Thanks! :)

Comment: I suggest a third table representing the many to many relationship between people and events.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: A Person can never have more than one Event, so it's only a one-to-many relationship (and "many" is never more than 2). And this is actually data from an external source I can't control. I already have code that can deal with "person1_name, person1_address, person2_name, person2_address" because I had another external dataset structured like that, so I wanted to create a view that would allow me to reuse that code.

Comment: Your query as is will return *2 separate rows* in case an event is related to two different Persons.

Comment: Uh hmm. There was an answer that used two joins, and that answer totally worked, but now it's deleted.

Comment: @oxguy3 that answer returned duplicate results. I'll post something in the same vein.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I just noticed the problem with it. Thanks, would much appreciate such an answer @Amine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `id` field in the `Person` table and you are guaranteed never to have more than 2 `Person` rows pointing to the same event, you can use this vanilla SQL solution :

```
SELECT
    Event.id,
    Event.description,
    P1.name AS person1_name,
    P2.name AS person2_name
  FROM Event
    LEFT JOIN Person P1
      ON Event.id = P1.event_id
    LEFT JOIN Person P2
     ON Event.id = P2.event_id 
WHERE P1.id < P2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Event.id,
    Event.description,
    P1.name AS person1_name,
    P2.name AS person2_name
  FROM Event
    LEFT JOIN Person P1
      ON Event.id = P1.event_id
    LEFT JOIN Person P2
     ON Event.id = P2.event_id AND P1.id <> P2.id
WHERE P2.id IS NULL
```

The first part of the query only returns events that have two matches. The second returns any event that has only one `Person` or is an orphan.

You can check this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de752/2). I omitted some of your columns but they're irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Actually there is no need for a `UNION`. Just add `P1.id < P2.id` in the `WHERE` clause and leave `AND P1.id < P2.id` out of the `ON` clause.

Comment: It seems my suggestion does not work in case there is only one, or none related Persons.

Comment: I misread you ; we do need a `UNION` here, however your suggestion is actually useful as it makes the conditions for the first half of the query simpler.

Comment: This query works perfectly! However, it turns out that the information I had gotten that said there would never be more than 2 persons was false, and I've now gotten more data that has 3 or more for a handful of events (government data is just loads of fun to work with). Nonetheless, thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, last_updated, description,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN name END) AS person1_name,            
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN address END) AS person1_address, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN name END) AS person2_name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN address END) AS person2_address
FROM (
  SELECT Event.id, Event.last_updated, Event.description,
         Person.name, Person.address,
         @rn := IF(@id = Event.id,
                   IF(@id := Event.id, @rn + 1, @rn + 1),
                   IF(@id := Event.id, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM Event
  LEFT JOIN Person ON Event.id = Person.event_id
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0, @id:=0) AS vars
  ORDER BY Event.id ) AS t
GROUP BY id, last_updated, description
```

This query uses a variable, `@rn`, in order to assign sequence numbers to rows within the same `Event.id` partition. Since at most two persons can be related to any event, `@rn` has a maximum value of 2.

The outer query uses `@rn` in order to perform *conditional aggregation*. This way we manage to merge two separate rows into one and place person1, person2 data at distinct fields.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c851/2)